# Discussion comments from Coursera

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I would like to do a simple machine learning project where I want to analyse comments from discussion forums on Coursera courses.

However, I am not sure if it is possible to do so programatically. So, providing a course page address, user name, password and getting all the discussion forums comments.

Being able to use Python for this would be awesome but I am language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access web pages with python using urllib:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

or the higher lever interface requests:
http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Then you still have to parse the content of the page and extract the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and use the requests package!